# Multiplayer Game Server Using deepsream

Tags: deepstream.io

I get to know that we can use List to make different rooms/lobby over server. I am new to server side development. I am bit confuse now. Like i need to make list(rooms) at server side. So which module I'll use to make server side code ? should i code using node js module of deepstream . Currently i have just connected to deepstream server and also connected rethinkdb and redis cache connector. So do i need to write a separate node module to do server side coding using node deepstream.io-client-js ? or do i need to implement a server over deepstream.io module?

it would be a great help if anyone can tell

Comment: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/building-a-multiplayer-space-shooter-part-i

Answer (score 0):

When using deepstream, the notion of 'server-side coding' is less clear than in traditional http-based applications. Usually the client will communicate directly with the deepstream server, and often application logic can be defined directly in the client. Security is then provided by configuring [Valve permissions](https://deepstream.io/docs/server/valve-permissions/) and authentication in the deepstream config.

For cases where application logic cannot be handled securely on the client, we recommend setting up Data Providers. Here, one or more 'provider' servers will run a deepstream client and provide access to a resource through deepstream's RPCs (remote procedure calls) or using the [Active Provider](https://deepstream.io/tutorials/core/active-data-providers/) pattern.